# Is there a way to directly read the content of a JSON file in a bucket Google Cloud Datastore via node.js without having to download it before?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I am a Python developer, but the circumstances of a project I am working on now, oblige me to find a solution in Node.js.

I have check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File)
In the class File, I have this method: createReadStream, but who force me to download in local before read it.

> However, the solution I search is just like to save the content in a variable so that I can read and interpret as I want.

This is the script of createReadStream() method:

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
var bucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

var fs = require('fs');
var remoteFile = bucket.file('image.png');
var localFilename = '/Users/stephen/Photos/image.png';

remoteFile.createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {})
  .on('response', function(response) {
    // Server connected and responded with the specified status
   })
  .on('end', function() {
    // The file is fully downloaded.
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localFilename));
```

Thank's for your understanding and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucket);
const remoteFile = bucket.file(file);

let buffer = '';
remoteFile.createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)})
  .on('data', function(response) {
    buffer += response
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    //console.log(buffer);
    res.send(buffer);
  })
```

Comment: I understand that you've been able to solve your issue, can you mark your answer as "accepted" to the benefit of the Stack Overflow community? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, I did the following code for you, works perfectly in a cloud function:

```js
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */

'use strict';

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.readJSON = (req, res) => {
  let file = gcs.bucket('YOUR_BUCKET').file('YOUR_FILE.JSON');
  let readStream = file.createReadStream();
  res.send(readStream);
};
```

and here you have the package.json (dependencies):

```js
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
   "@google-cloud/storage": "1.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your help, but I haven't use cloud function to resolve this.