# How to access file data from firebase storage without downloading

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a URL for my file type `.ies` that is uploaded on firebase storage and I want to read the content inside the file but when I hit URL on the browser it only returns the information about the file, not the content
Example link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/westgatedash-d1341.appspot.com/o/documents%2FIES%2FCDL2-45W-M-120V_IESNA2002.IES

but when I use query params alt=media it downloads that I don't want.
Are there any query params to get the data of the file? or any way to achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, each call is different and for different purposes:

- [Listing objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#rest-list-objects):

> To list the objects in a bucket:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o"
```

- [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects):

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  -o "SAVE_TO_LOCATION" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME?alt=media"
```

The difference when hitting the endpoint is, precisely, the `alt=media` param. What I understand is that you might want to stream the object? If so, you can achieve it through the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#cloud-console). For instance:

To handle the file on a Cloud Function you can follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) you will find more detailed info. As a summary, to download a file:

```
// Download file from bucket.
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
const metadata = {
  contentType: contentType,
};
await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
```

This will save the image to a temporary folder since this is the recommended way to do it.

> Use `gcs.bucket.file(filePath).download` to download a file to a temporary directory on your Cloud Functions instance. In this location, you can process the file as needed.

**EDIT**

According to [Downloads Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#downloads):

You can send download requests to Cloud Storage in the following ways:

- Simple download: Downloading objects to a destination.
- **Streaming download**: Downloading data to a process.
- Sliced object download: Downloading large objects.

In the [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs), following the GitHub Repo: [For C++](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/google/cloud/storage/examples/storage_object_samples.cc) it shows a stream downloading:

```
void ReadObject(google::cloud::storage::Client client,
                std::vector<std::string> const& argv) {
  //! [read object] [START storage_download_file]
  namespace gcs = google::cloud::storage;
  [](gcs::Client client, std::string const& bucket_name,
     std::string const& object_name) {
    gcs::ObjectReadStream stream = client.ReadObject(bucket_name, object_name);

    int count = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(stream, line, '\n')) {
      ++count;
    }

    std::cout << "The object has " << count << " lines\n";
  }
  //! [read object] [END storage_download_file]
  (std::move(client), argv.at(0), argv.at(1));
}
```

But for [NodeJs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/downloadFile.js), for some reason, it doesn't. I was not able to find any example of that. On the other hand there are other questions in SatckOverflow with the same question, i.e: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392131/is-there-a-way-to-directly-read-the-content-of-a-json-file-in-a-bucket-google-cl):

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucket);
const remoteFile = bucket.file(file);

let buffer = '';
remoteFile.createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)})
  .on('data', function(response) {
    buffer += response
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    //console.log(buffer);
    res.send(buffer);
  })
```

Comment: actually, I don't want to download the file at any point. What I need is to read directly the content inside the file. I hosted on a different server which is giving me what I want and the link to that file is here: http://cnw.hostbumpup.website/wp-content/themes/aduma/LWA-12W-120V_IESNA2002.IES
but when I hit the URL that firebase bucket provided me it gives me only the information about the file. And I am not dealing with images right now.

Comment: Joss Baron by the way thanks for the effort. I really appreciated it and liked it. Please review the above comment and tell me if you could help with that. Thanks, Man (y)

Comment: sorry for the delay, i update the answer with an example.